# Is "fancy" used to describe a gay person?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Once upon a time, I chose the word '***fancy***' as my nickname in real life (e.g. "feel free to call me 'Fancy' sometimes") because I thought it's a good word, which have a sense of *elegantly fashionable or sophisticated* **or** *of superior grade; fine*.

But later on, some of my American friends (I'm not quite sure where they were born, but one of them worked in Oregon) suggested that I should change that name because **fancy** is used to describe a gay person. I felt embarrassed so I looked it up, but I couldn't find any dictionaries have it defined. The closest definition I got is:

> c. To take a romantic interest in (someone): *Do you think he fancies her*?

But it seems it's not relevant to anything gay. So, is it common to use **fancy** to describe a gay person? Is it a regional usage (I guess it's mainly in the US)?

Comment: You don't normally "choose a nickname" Your nickname is usually just a shortening of your name "Daniel -> Dan" for example.  Sometimes people are known for particular acts or features but these are chosen by their friends: "We call him 'hedgehog' because of his spikey hair". But can't just choose a word for a nickname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **fancy** itself is not registered in dictionaries as **someone (especially male) who is gay**, though there are some compound nouns that have **fancy** in them:

> fancy man (male lover)
>
> fancy pants (conceited, narcissistic male person)
>
> **fancy Dan (~ fop, dandy, jemmy, toff (GB), clothes-horse, beau)**

The last one is the closest to someone who might be referred to as gay, so there must be a reason why some people (or Americans, as you wrote) use this word. Perhaps they left Dan off the word, and so they coined a word with a new meaning (though it is my supposition). And if it's only regionally used, I can't tell.

Comment: I can't find the reference of "fancy Dam" on the web.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it! I corrected the word. It's "fancy Dan."